# Transfering and Offline installing net-tools in an Ubuntu Server with no internet (VM with host-only enabled)

Tags: linux, debian, ubuntu, package-management, vmware

I don't know how to install net-tools on an ubuntu server that's not an internet facing machine and for some reasons, I don't want it to be.

This is a VM set to host-only for the time being.

Is there a way to transfer a .deb package, such as this: https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-arm64/net-tools_1.60+git20181103.0eebece-1_arm64.deb.html
into my VM, then run `sudo dpkg -i packet_name` to install it without having to use Internet at all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sure, you could just copy the file onto your VM (`scp` if ssh works), then just install it.

Problem is: packages have dependencies, and you wouldn't have copied these.

Two options:

## 1. Provision a new VM with the software you want

First option, and the one I'd recommend:

VMs are typically *provisioned*, then deployed and then not touched anymore afterwards: So, use your favorite provisioning tool to get a VM that has all the software you need, and then just add your specific configuration to it. The big advantage is that you can do all the things online to set up all the software, and then you disconnect and copy over everything that should not be on a machine with internet connectivity.

`cloud-init` is a popular tool for that. I personally mostly use `ansible` on plain VMs, though. That makes adding this piece of software nothing more than adding a line to a yaml file.

## 2. Use `apt-offline`

You can use `apt-offline` to prepare a list of packages that need to be installed so that you can install the software you want, then transfer that list to a machine with internet access, download the needed packages, transfer these back to your offline VM, then install them there.

1. install apt-offline: go to https://packages.ubuntu.com and download the .deb file of `apt-offline` for your architecture (it has no special dependencies, so you only need that)
2. use scp to copy the deb file onto your offline server
3. `sudo dpkg -i apt-offline*something.deb` on the server
4. generate a request for a package index update and consequent installation of a package on the offline machine: `sudo apt-offline set --install-packages PACKAGENAME --update apt-offline.sig`
5. copy the that apt-offline.sig file to your online machine
6. on the online machine, execute that request: `apt-offline get --bundle bundle.zip apt-offline.sig`
7. copy the bundle.zip to your offline machine
8. on the offline machine, `sudo apt-offline install bundle.zip` and
9. finally, you can install the package on your offline machine: `sudo apt install PACKAGENAME`.

Comment: Thank you a lot! This is perfectly explained.

Comment: Mine had a dependency of python3-magic, but that was all, so it was easy to install only that one first.

Comment: Thanks for this answer - I keep coming back to these steps and this is a better explanation how apt-offline works than it provides via man pages. Kudos (y)